# Modifying Javascript collections while iterating over them

Tags: javascript, collections, iterator

Is there a formal definition of how Javascript collection iterators should behave when the collections are modified while iterating over them? For example an Array iterator seems unable to handle splice, while a Map iterator can handle delete. Tested on Chrome.

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (let item of array)
{
  console.log(item);   // Writes a, c, d
  if (item === "a") array.splice(0, 1);
  if (item === "c") array.push("d");
}

let map = new Map();
map.set("a", "A");
map.set("b", "B");
map.set("c", "C");
for (let [key, item] of map)
{
  console.log(key);   // Writes a, b, c, d
  if (key === "a") map.delete("a");
  if (key === "c") map.set("d", "D");
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do something that is not recommended? (modifying collections while iterating over them)

Comment: Well, a Map and an Array are quite different data structures. And `Map.delete` and `Array.splice` ain't exactly the same, either. How would you define the operation `map.splice({id:1}, 3, { id: 6}, {id: 7}, {id: 8})`?

Comment: Nir Alfasi: Please point me to the definition of an Array and Map, where it says it isn't allowed. C# throws an exception when you do, JS does not, so I assumed it is internally supported.

Answer (score 2):

The code is working essentially as intended in these cases but it's sometimes hard to understand exactly which sequencing of read/updates is going on.

Take a look the snippet below - it's still your code but marked up with a bit more logging. You'll see at each step what's going on and I think this should make it a bit clearer as to why you're getting the results you are.

```js
let array = ["a", "b", "c"];

let i = 0;
for (let item of array)
{
  console.log("[iterator item: " + item + "] [iterator value " + i +"] [current array:", array + "]");
  if (item === "a") {array.splice(0, 1);console.log("spliced 1 item after reading: " + item);}
  if (item === "c") {array.push("d"); console.log("pushed 1 item after reading: " + item)};
  i++;
}

console.log(array);

let map = new Map();
map.set("a", "A");
map.set("b", "B");
map.set("c", "C");
for (let [key, item] of map)
{
  console.log("iterated over key: " + key);   // Writes a, b, c, d
  if (key === "a") {map.delete("a"), console.log("deleted a")};
  if (key === "c") {map.set("d", "D"), console.log("iterated over key c and added a new map set for d-D")};
}

console.log(mapEntriesToString(map));

function mapEntriesToString(entries) {
  return Array
    .from(entries, ([k, v]) => `\n  ${k}: ${v}`)
    .join("") + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. If the implementation of the iterators is described somewhere, then I guess they work as intended, but AFAIK this isn't described anywhere. I can only guess that the array iterator is internally replaced with a for-loop, so when I remove "a", the next iteration will skip past b and go straight to c. But the Map it doesn't skip b, so its not like a for-loop over the keys, so how is it done exactly? And if it is not recommended or allowed to modify collections while iterating, why doesn't it throw an exception, like it does in other languages?

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanna go deep in this, then you at first should review [ECMAScript 2020 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-%25arrayiteratorprototype%25-object) or any other version required for your purpuses. Then when get anderstanding how lang specification works for arrays you can go to next step and select engine which implended this spec. V8 as example used in Chrome and in Node.js

You can view iterator implementation by yourself in [v8 source code](https://v8.dev/docs/source-code).

So this how you can get full understanding about any feature in any lang

Comment: Thanks Layonez. I was hoping that it is explained clearly somewhere. It is strange that a language can have operations that have undefined outcomes. Usually an operation is either illegal (throws an exception) or if it is legal then all side effects are clearly defined.

Comment: I think if you dig into any programming language, you will understand that there is not and cannot be perfect documentation, and many interesting results depend on the compiler version or some build flag or specific OS version or weather. But in js, thanks to weak typing I guess, it all really lies on the surface

Comment: Assembly for a specific processor is perfectly defined. So is a C compiler for that specific processor. And so on. Most languages are almost perfectly defined, or they wouldn't be popular.

Answer (score 1):

The ECMAScript 2024 specification defines [Map](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-map-objects) using an abstraction of an indexed array. It is an abstraction, because the implementation may not be an array, but can be any data structure meeting the performance requirements and the observable semantics as defined using this array.

Any [set](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-map.prototype.set) with new key will append into the abstract array and [clear](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-map.prototype.clear) or [delete](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-map.prototype.delete) will not remove the element, but set the key and value to empty. [Iterator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-map-iterator-objects) will iterate through array indices and yields keys, values or elements from the array indices when the key is not empty.

This results in semantics where the collection can be modified safely during iteration.

`delete` from before the iterator will not cause next element to be skipped. A set will not cause same elements to be iterated twice nor will the newly added element be skipped. But there is the caveat that to `set` new keys (or keys that were deleted during the iteration) during iteration may cause the iteration to never end.

The [Array](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array-objects) is an object indexed by numerical indices. The [iterator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array-iterator-objects) is defined to iterate the `Array` by index. Iterator does not iterate over the values of the array. As a [splice](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.splice) reassigns values to new indices. This results that some values may not be seen if the array is modified such that values move from after the iteration index to already iterated indices.

To answer the question, there is no single collection iterator definition, but each collection type has own iterator types defined.